# C++ Program leaving my for loop prematurely

Tags: c++

I'm working on a little poker application and i've run into the first problem I just can't seem to comprehend.

```
while (allplayersGood != 1) { //round table till all decided
                cout << "TOP OF WHILE LOOP";
                for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++) { //for loop for decisions from non button or blinds
                    int player_decision = 1;
                    char choice;
                    if ((players[i].playerhand.card1.value != 'F') && (players[i].playerhand.card1.value != 'C')) {
                        if ((players[i].blind != 1 && players[i].blind != 2) && players[i].button != true) {
                            cout << "\n\n";
                            cout << "           POT: " << playerTable->currentPot;
                            cout << "\n";
                            for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++) {
                                cout << "Player " << players[i].playernumber;
                                cout << " (" << players[i].chip_amount << ")    ";
                            }
                            while (player_decision == 1) {
                                if (playerTable->currentBet > players[i].currentBet) {
                                    cout << "\n\nPlayer " << players[i].playernumber << " ("; players[i].playerhand.printhand(); cout << ") " << "Type F for Fold, B for Call, R for Raise: ";
                                    cin >> choice;
                                    players[i].choice = choice;
                                    if (choice == 'F') {
                                        player_decision = 0;
                                        players[i].fold();
                                    }
                                    if (choice == 'R') {
                                        player_decision = 0;
                                        players[i].bet(playerTable);
                                    }
                                    if (choice == 'B') {
                                        player_decision = 0;
                                        players[i].call(playerTable);
                                    }

                                }
                                if ((playerTable->currentBet == players[i].currentBet) && player_decision != 0) { //big blind after round table
                                    cout << "\n\nPlayer " << players[i].playernumber << " ("; players[i].playerhand.printhand(); cout << ") " << "Type C for Check, R for Raise: ";
                                    cin >> choice;
                                    players[i].choice = choice;
                                    if (choice == 'B') {
                                        player_decision = 0;
                                        players[i].bet(playerTable);
                                    }
                                    if (choice == 'C') {
                                        if (players[i].check(playerTable) == true) {
                                            player_decision = 0;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (players[i].blind == 1 || players[i].blind == 2) {
                        if (players[i].blind == 1) {
                            players[i].chip_amount -= sblind;
                            playerTable->currentPot += sblind;
                            players[i].blind = 0;
                            players[i].currentBet = sblind;
                        }
                        if (players[i].blind == 2) {
                            players[i].chip_amount -= bblind;
                            playerTable->currentPot += bblind;
                            players[i].blind = 0;
                            players[i].currentBet = bblind;
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++) { //seperate loop for button and blinds that were ignored in loop above
                    int player_decision = 1;
                    char choice;
                    if (players[i].button == true || players[i].blind == 1) { //button and small blind
                        cout << "\n\n";
                        cout << "           POT: " << playerTable->currentPot;
                        cout << "\n";
                        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++) {
                            cout << "Player " << players[i].playernumber;
                            cout << " (" << players[i].chip_amount << ")    ";
                        }
                        while (player_decision == 1) {
                            cout << "\n\nPlayer " << players[i].playernumber << " ("; players[i].playerhand.printhand(); cout << ") " << "Type F for Fold, B for Call, R for Raise: ";
                            cin >> choice;
                            players[i].choice = choice;
                            if (choice == 'F') {
                                player_decision = 0;
                                players[i].fold();
                            }
                            if (choice == 'R') {
                                player_decision = 0;
                                players[i].bet(playerTable);
                            }
                            if (choice == 'B') {
                                player_decision = 0;
                                players[i].call(playerTable);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    cout << i;
                    if (players[i].blind == 2) { //big blind
                        cout << "\n\n";
                        cout << "           POT: " << playerTable->currentPot;
                        cout << "\n";
                        for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++) {
                            cout << "Player " << players[i].playernumber;
                            cout << " (" << players[i].chip_amount << ")    ";
                        }
                        while (player_decision == 1) {
                            cout << "\n\nPlayer " << players[i].playernumber << " ("; players[i].playerhand.printhand(); cout << ") " << "C for Check, R for Raise: ";
                            cin >> choice;
                            players[i].choice = choice;
                            if (choice == 'C') {
                                if (players[i].check(playerTable) == true) {
                                    player_decision = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            if (choice == 'R') {
                                player_decision = 0;
                                players[i].bet(playerTable);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                int playersBetting = 0;
                int playersGood = 0;
                int playersChecked = 0;
                int playersNot = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++) {
                    if (players[i].playerhand.card1.value != 'F') {
                        playersBetting++;
                        if (players[i].currentBet == playerTable->currentBet) {
                            playersGood++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < PLAYER_COUNT; i++) {
                    if (players[i].playerhand.card1.value != 'F') {
                        if (players[i].isChecked == true) {
                            playersChecked++;
                        }
                        else {
                            playersNot++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                cout << playersBetting << playersGood;
                if ((playersBetting == playersGood) || (playersNot == 0)) {
                    cout << "NEXT ROUND STARTED";
                }
            }
```

The issue is, during the second for loop with comment "seperate loop for button and blinds that were ignored in loop above" after the first if statement succeeds because players[0] has button equal to true, the player will make the terminal input as a decision, and the program will exit the for loop and go down to the end with the playersBetting and playersGood loops, then return back to the for loop at index 1 correctly.

I'm sorry if this is a little complicated to understand there is a lot of code that I probably didn't put into context very well, if you need any extra information please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? It is plenty of nested loops and conditions, so it makes things harder

Comment: Also you should do less variables shadowing, having nested fors all using 'i' is not exactly a good idea, can lead to issues.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have different loops inside one another. This is possible, but in that case, you need to use another loop variable (`j` instead of `i`), let me show you what happens:

```
for i ...
   for j ...
```

This causes the following values to be taken for `i` and `j`:

```
i j
1 1
1 2
1 ...
1 n
2 1
2 2
2 ...
2 n
...
n 1
n 2
...
n n
```

... and here it stops.

If you keep using `i` in the inner loop, this is what you get:

```
i (outside loop) i (inside loop)
1                1
2                2                // indeed: changing i inside also changes i outside
...              ...
n                n
```

So you jump out of the outside loop, even after just having looped the inside loop one time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was unrelated to the actual loop and actually had to do with a value I changed upstream. Thank you for the few who tried to help with such little context haha

Have a good one